# Openshift check what contains every gear

Tags: openshift

How can I check what contains every gear.

Now I'm using haproxy, mysql and a python web service.

I like to know how check where is every cartridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "rhc app show  --gears" command to show which cartridge is installed on which gear (along with other information about them).  Or you can use "rhc app show  --gears ssh" to show the ssh connection information for all of your gears.